# How to fix 'expected * but argument is of type **' error when trying to hand over a pointer to a function

Tags: c, function, pointers

I try to hand over a pointer to a function:

This is the pointer that I want to hand over:

```
content_t *encc = malloc(sizeof(*encc));
```

The pointer is type of this struct

```
typedef struct _content {
    int length;
    char **lines;    
} content_t;
```

This is where I hand the pointer over to the function: 
`write_content("enc-file.txt", &encc);`

Thats the head of my function:
`void write_content(char *filename, content_t *content)`

I receive following error-message:

```
expected 'struct content_t *' but argument is of type 'struct content_t **'
```

What am I doing wrong here? 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Remove the addressof operator from `&encc` - it is already a pointer, so it should only be `encc`

Answer (score 3):

`encc` is already of type `content_t *`.  By adding `&` it gives you an expression of type `content_t **`, which doesn't match what the function expects.

The address-of operator is not needed here, so remove it.

```
write_content("enc-file.txt", encc);
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
 write_content("enc-file.txt", &encc);
```

to

```
 write_content("enc-file.txt", encc);
```